# Как убрать огромные поля при компиляции vimtex в pdf?

Tags: pdf, vim, latex

Недавно я начал пользоваться latex, для компиляции использую vimtex а для просмотра - sumathraPDF. Vimtex компилирует его так, что в конечном pdf остаются отступы по краям на пол страницы, и шрифт получается как бы маленьким (я посмотрел в ещё одном ридере xodo, там тоже самое). В sumathraPDF есть масштабирование по контенту, но оно работает криво. Может, есть другие ридеры, которые справляются с этими отступами, или можно изменить настройки в vimtex? Подойдет любое решение. И, заранее спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, приложите исходный файл в формате latex. Vimtex - это всего лишь текстовый редактор с какими-то макросами для компиляции. SumatraPDF - это всего лишь программа для просмотра файла PDF. Любой другой просмотрщик для PDF покажет то же самое. Вся проблема именно в Вашем коде в исходном файле. Но даже не глядя на исходник, могу сказать, что Вы использовали документ с параметрами по умолчанию, который подразумевает шрифт 10пт и формат рабочего поля для листа A5 (ширина текста 10.8см), поэтому при наложении на формат листа A4 (это тоже идет по умолчанию) получаются огромные поля.

Comment: Я честно говоря где-то читал, что LaTeX для верстки, а не для дизайна, и что настраивать ничего не нужно. Поэтому даже не подозревал, что можно изменить оформление текста в tex файле. Спасибо большое, помогли

Comment: Да, это верно, LaTeX - для верстки. Но есть много разных стран со своими типографскими традициями и особенностями, есть много разных документов со своим специфичным оформлением. LaTeX не может по умолчанию удовлетворять всем таким условиям одновременно, и потому, имеет большое количество параметров и команд, которые влияют на оформление документа. Какие-то параметры задаются через класс документа, какие-то специальными командами, а какие-то - через пакеты расширений.